# Geometric Transformation of Distorted Grid Lines Using Image Processing

Tags: image-processing, matlab, 2d, geometry

If the grid-lines in the image (attached: distort1.jpeg) [image: distorted image] are distorted and squares in image appears distorted a bit. What would be the best and easy approach to convert them to perfect squares (as shown in correct.jpeg) image. [image: correct image]